# Using Regex to replace a Class Properties in string

Tags: c#, regex

Please, I want to replace a class properties (or fields) in string, I want to use Regex, but I'am not familiarised with regular expressions. 
Example of string :

```
string Source = "Dear @Customer.Civility, @Customer.Name @Customer.Surname\n\n " +
"About your bill dated @Order.Date..."
```

I want to catch the occurences of classes properties like "@Customer.Name" , "@Order.Date" and replace them with its values using reflections.

Is there AnyOne to Help me, Please ( Excuse my English...)

Comment: what's wrong with `string.Replace()` here?

Comment: What is the object you are using reflection on? Can you paste the code/definition of it?

Comment: Also, have you tried any code so far? We would like to see that as well.

Comment: @rmayer06, please don't write your assumptions instead of author. He doesn't specified that "string pattern is subject to change" in original question, so your edit was not "minor cleanup" as it was claimed.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: While that's true, the statement "replace them with its values using reflections" suggests they might have something more dynamic in mind (or else they are just determined to make this really complicated, but I'll give them the benefit of the doubt). Either way, it doesn't hurt to make several suggestions on how you might tackle this particular problem.

Comment: Yes, it is true that I made an assumption. It would be nice if @relghers would comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually interesting challenge. I used Matt's regex.

```
var customer = new Customer() {  Civility = "Mr.", Name = "Max", Surname = "Mustermann" };
var order = new Order();
string Source = "Dear @Customer.Civility, @Customer.Name @Customer.Surname\n\n About your bill dated @Order.Date...";
string s = BringTheMash(Source, new { Customer = customer, Order = order });

Console.WriteLine(s);


private static string BringTheMash(string format, object p)
{
    string result = format;
    var regex = new Regex(@"@(?<object>\w+)\.?(?<property>\w+)");
    foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(format))
    {
        var obj = m.Groups[1].ToString();
        var prop = m.Groups[2].ToString();

        var parameter = p.GetType().GetProperty(obj).GetValue(p);
        var value = parameter.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(parameter);

        result = result.Replace(m.Value, value.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

I didn't add any exception handling, which would happen if objects didn't have required properties.

Comment: all classes and properties in the source are known and we can easily test their existance **thanks**

Comment: minor fix, in your `foreach` loop it should be `regex.Matches(format)`. Otherwise, great answer. I also named the groups for a reason!

Answer (score 2):

Are you really want to go such a complicated way?

Why just don't have a string like

```
string Source = "Dear {0}, {1} {2}\n\n " + "About your bill dated {3}..."
```

and later format it like

```
string result = string.Format(Source, 
    Customer.Civility, 
    Customer.Name, 
    Customer.Surname, 
    Order.Date)
```

Comment: -1: does not answer the question. I think he wants something for the general case, and not have to re-write code every time. Makes a lot of sense to me, actually.

Comment: I dont now what **Class** is in the Source text ( of course there could be one , two or three, like Customer, Ordrer or paiements )   and How much occurences of the class are repeated... **thanks**

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the comments on why regex might not be the right solution, if you do need a regex (because you need this to be more dynamic, maybe processing several templates for example), something like:

```
@\w+\.?\w+
```

Ought to do the trick.

It matches the literal `@` followed by 1 or more word characters (`\w` is shorthand for the class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, i.e. all the letters, digits and the underscore, which should cover you), followed by an optional `.` (just remove the `?` if you want it to be non-optional) and then 1 or more word characters.

You can use it like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"@\w+\.?\w+");

string Source = "Dear @Customer.Civility, @Customer.Name @Customer.Surname\n\n " +
    "About your bill dated @Order.Date...";

foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(Source)) 
{
    // do whatever processing you want with the matches here.
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}",m.Index,m.Value));   
}
```

Logs:

```
5:@Customer.Civility
25:@Customer.Name
40:@Customer.Surname
82:@Order.Date
```

With the index and the text of the match, you should have everything you need to make your replacements.

If you want to make it easier to extract the object and the property from your matches, you can use grouping in your regex. Something like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"@(?<object>\w+)\.?(?<property>\w+)");

string Source = "Dear @Customer.Civility, @Customer.Name @Customer.Surname\n\n " +
    "About your bill dated @Order.Date...";

foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(Source)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index: {0}, Object: {1}, Property: {2}",
                      m.Index,m.Groups["object"],m.Groups["property"]));
}
```

Will log:

```
Index: 5, Object: Customer, Property: Civility
Index: 25, Object: Customer, Property: Name
Index: 40, Object: Customer, Property: Surname
Index: 82, Object: Order, Property: Date
```

So now you've identified the index, the object that you need to get the substitution from and the property you need from that object.

Comment: may be add rule for exclude number in the first letter of identifier `@(?<object>[^0-9]\w*)\.?(?<property>[^0-9]\w*)`